# Grid line view as background in Highchartjs?

Tags: javascript, gridview, highcharts, linechart, gridlines

In Highchartjs we can have grid lines based on series points. However I'd like to modify that by adding as many grid lines as I prefer.

In other words, I'd like to set this [Grid-line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIwCr.jpg) as a background for this [`JsFiddle highchartjs line-graph`](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/)

From looking at the docs, both the [`xAxis`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis) and [`yAxis`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis) support gridlines

The question really is; Is it possible to do this? If so please shed some light to this matter.

Comment: Thanks you, thats exactly what I was looking for. However, can each square have 5 small boxes rather than 4 (i.e. 5x5) instead of 4x4? @ewolden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be set pretty much as you said:

```
xAxis: {
  minorTickInterval: 0.25,
  gridLineWidth: 1
}, 
yAxis: {
  minorTickInterval: 0.25,
  gridLineWidth: 1
}
```

The `minorTickInterval` governs how many "boxes" you have. Since the tick interval is 1 here, I set the `minorTickInterval` to 0.25, 1/0.25 = 4. Setting it to 0.2 would give 5 small boxes. Naturally if you change scale on the axes this will change as well.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/t0bzyywe/1/

**API refs**: [`gridLineWidth`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineWidth) and [`minorTickInterval`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.minorTickInterval)

Comment: Thank you so much. That helped greatly :)